# Does the Citroen C4 2012 Bluetooth audio system play music and connects the phone?

Tags: audio, citroen, citroen-c4

I know that Citroen C4 can come equipped with a Bluetooth audio system, which can connect your phone too. I was wondering is anyone tried playing music from the iphone to the audio system using bluetooth?

Comment: My 2009 C5 used to be able to play music from a bluetooth device.

Comment: By device you mean the built-in one right?

Comment: The stereo would stream music from my phone or mp3 player.

Comment: Stereo = the stereo system you received with the car (manufactured by Citroen)?

Comment: yes - the built in stereo

Comment: Ok, but how can you do that?
Beacuse on my fone i can' t select my car for my music app. Do i have to enable a setting?
A screenshot from my fone:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfaYV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Citroen C4 OEM stereo can play music from bluetooth devices such as android or IOS based phones.